# Check for URL in WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, child-theming

I want to restrict access to a specific URL of my WordPress-Site for logged-in users only. So if someone isnt logged in, they should be redirected to homepage.

I guess its working with this code in functions.php

```
if (!(is_user_logged_in()) && is_page('PAGE-ID')){
    wp_redirect( home_url() . '/login' );
    exit;
}
```

But unfortunately this site has no Page-ID, so I have to target the URL instead. How can I do this?

Comment: `this site has no ID` means? no page ID?

Comment: yes right, it shows our Amazon Inventory - nothing more than a huge table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this.

```
global $post;
$pageUrl = get_permalink($post->ID);

if (!(is_user_logged_in()) && $pageUrl=='http://yoursiteurl.com/page/'){
    wp_redirect( home_url() . '/login' );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Important thing, don't use cache!

```
if ( !(is_page('pag-2') || is_page('pag-1')) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Location: page-to-redirect');
```